# Accessing point32 under geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am new to ROS so excuse me for the silly doubt.
There is a topic being published by a package, of type **geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped**. On executing rosmsg  show this is what I got
std_msgs/Header header
uint32 seq
time stamp
string frame_id
geometry_msgs/Polygon polygon
geometry_msgs/Point32[] points
float32 x
float32 y
float32 z
Now I want to subscribe this topic and access Point x,y,z. How do I do it?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266767/accessing-point32-under-geometry_msgs/polygonstamped/) by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29), the Subscriber part, exchange `std_msgs/String` with `geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped` and then access with `msg->polygon.points[i].x` etc. Note that `points` is actually an `std::vector` so make sure to access this correctly.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on 2017-07-19**:
my callback function looks like void Callback(const PolygonStampedConstPtr& poly). Inside callback I am doing float u = poly->polygon.points.x; float v = poly->polygon.points.y;. But according to your answer what should my i be?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-07-19**:
`i` depends on the vector. You have multiple elements, so it should be within the range of the number of polygons. You could also iterate over the full vector...

**Comment by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on 2017-07-19**:
It solved my problem. Thanks mig.
I also want the time difference between consecutive calls to callback function. Can you tell how it would be done? I was thinking of difference b/w ros::time::now, but don't know how to use it!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-07-20**:
please post a new question..

**Comment by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on 2017-07-22**:
Yaa got it!